# Python bit backing for readability (if possible)

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I have three binary values that make up a byte as follows:

```
mod    reg     r/m
- -   - - -   - - -
```

What would be the best way to add these three together?

Currently I'm doing it like:

```
MOD = 0b01
REG = 0b010
R_M = 0b100
MOD_REG_RM = MOD<<6 | REG<<3 | R_M
>>> f'{MOD_REG_RM:>08b}'
'01010100'
```

Is there a better way to work with packing binary values in python? I'm hoping that I can do something along the lines of:

```
MOD_REG_RM = [MOD + REG + R_M]
MOD = 0b01
...
```

It's pseudocode, but much more readable than the above with all the bitshifting. What's the best (i.e., most readable) way to do this?

Comment: There are [bitstruct](https://pypi.org/project/bitstruct/) and [bitarray](https://pypi.org/project/bitarray/) modules on PyPI; would either of those help?

Comment: In my opinion the bitshifting and or-ing is perfectly readable. It's seen quite often in code in many languages. Also I don't know of a better way to do it with the Python standard library and installing a PyPI module for this problem seems like overkill.

Comment: @sabik would you want to show an example of how that could be used? I haven't used or even heard of any of those packages.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 Can you first try reading the docs and then ask specific questions about what you find incomprehensible? I find `bitarray` in particular suitable for your needs.

Comment: Alternatively, you can make the parts strings first, e.g. `MOD = '01'`, `REG = '010'`, `R_M = '100'`, and then do `MOD_REG = MOD + REG + R_M`, and then `MOD_REG = int(MOD_REG, 2)` to actually make it an integer.